# Expanding and Collapsing RecyclerView item showing wrong behaviour

Tags: android

I am building an android project where I use RecyclerView to show the list items. The list items are CardViews. I have two clickable icons in each card, one is responsible for expanding the card and show the rest of the view and another is responsible for collapsing the card to its previous state.

My problem is, when I expand one card(for example: 1st card) and scroll down I see another card(for example: 10th card) has been expanded. I know, this happens because the 1st card is recycled and used in place of 10th card. But as I did not clicked expand icon in the 10th card it should be in collapsed state. How can I achieve this?

I am sorry if the question is very naive.

This is my RecyclerViewAdapter code.

```
private List<String> mDataSet;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public CardView cardView;
    public TextView headLine, newsPaperName, time, newsDetail;
    public ImageView newsImage, iconExpand, iconCollapse;
    public int minHeight, maxHeight;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.new_item_card_view);
        newsImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_image);
        headLine = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.headline);
        newsPaperName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_paper);
        time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        iconExpand = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_expand);
        iconCollapse = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_collapse);
        newsDetail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_detail);


        cardView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                cardView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                // Set the minimum height of the CardView
                minHeight = cardView.getHeight() - newsDetail.getMeasuredHeight();
                // Set the maximum height of the card view
                maxHeight = cardView.getHeight();

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = cardView.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = minHeight;
                cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                return true;
            }
        });

        iconExpand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                expandView();
            }
        });

        iconCollapse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                collapseView();
            }
        });
    }

    private void collapseView() {

        ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(cardView.getMeasuredHeightAndState(), minHeight);
        anim.setDuration(150);
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = cardView.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = val;
                cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                iconExpand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                iconCollapse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
        anim.start();
    }
    private void expandView() {
        newsDetail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_detail);

        ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(cardView.getMeasuredHeightAndState(), maxHeight);
        anim.setDuration(150);
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = cardView.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = val;
                cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                iconCollapse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                iconExpand.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        });
        anim.start();
    }
}

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> myDataSet) {
    mDataSet = myDataSet;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.headLine.setText("Torem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eli");
    holder.newsPaperName.setText("Crux: Covering all things Catholic");
    holder.time.setText(" - 54 min. ago");
    holder.newsDetail.setText("NEW York The U.S. Securities and exchange Commission on Friday" +
            "denied a request to list what would");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }
```

here return position instead of super.getItemId()

and implement setHasStableIds(true);`